# BitTorrent Local Peer Discovery when using SOCKS

Tags: multicast, bittorrent, socks, torrent

I am writing a simple BitTorrent client with Local Peer Discovery and SOCKS5 support.

Are these technologies mutually exclusive? Should I disable Local Peer Discovery when using SOCKS proxy?

Comment: depends on the reason you want to use SOCKS

Comment: Some organizations have Internet connectivity only through the SOCKS server. I want the client to work in these situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these technologies mutually exclusive

No. You can open regular sockets to listen for local connections found via LPD and use SOCKS for proxied connections.